# Variable store data field value in sql query

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @string nvarchar(20)
set @string=(select [Bill Period] from [sqldata].[dbo].[jun1])
select substring (@string,1,3)
```

i got just single value from the entire column [Bill period],i want all the record from [Bill Period] to @string but it is not working.

how to increment table INDEX and fetch the records

```
declare @INDEX int
set @INDEX=1
while(@INDEX<3)
begin
Declare @string nvarchar(20)
set @string=(select [Bill Period] from [sqldata].[dbo].[jun1])
select substring (@string,1,3)
set @INDEX=@INDEX+1
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct table?

Comment: Do you have a table named `jun1` in your database `sqldata`?

Answer (score 2):

If [sqldata] is your DataBase name thenthe correct order would be:

```
select [Bill Period] from [sqldata].[dbo].[jun1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a column in a select statement:

Taking:

```
[dbo].[sqldata].[jun1]
```

- `dbo` is the schema
- `sqldata` is the table - this is where you should select from
- `jun1` I don't know what this is.

Try:

```
Select Declare @string nvarchar(20)
set @string=(select [Bill Period] from [dbo].[sqldata])
select substring (@string,1,3)
```

or explain your problem / schema better.

Answer (score 1):

it Should be like

```
[sqldata].[dbo].[jun1]
^database ^Schema ^Tablename
```

The write Query:

```
Declare @string nvarchar(20)
set @string=(select [Bill Period] from [sqldata].[dbo].[jun1])
select substring (@string,1,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are using correct `server_name.database_name.schema_name.object_name`. You don't need to use all those multipart identifiers but general idea is you should be looking at the correct place.

**Also, You should SELECT the TOP 1 record before assigning it into a variable, otherwise it will break once you get more than one record in the table**

```
Declare @String nvarchar(20)

Select Top 1 @String = [Bill Period] 
From  jun1    -- on correct database 
Order by yourColumn

Select substring (@string,1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

something wrong is in your query. make sure that you are calling it in a right way.

as Luv answered-

```
[sqldata].[dbo].[jun1]
^database ^Schema ^Tablename
```

this is the format which is supported by SQL server.